# AccessToken from AWS Java SDK does not satisfy regular expression pattern

Tags: access-token, amazon-cognito

we are tring to create an access token from Java SDK and it throws the following error:
"com.amazonaws.services.cognitoidp.model.InvalidParameterException: 1 validation error detected: Value at 'accessToken' failed to satisfy constraint: Member must satisfy regular expression pattern: http://A-Za-z0-9-_=.+ (Service: AWSCognitoIdentityProvider; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidParameterException; Request ID: 6e1d763a-b8c2-11e7-8bcc-fd6f3789064c)"

We have checked in the JWT Web page the access token is correct and has a proper value and also checked that it satisfies the regular expression http://A-Za-z0-9-_=.+.

We've generated the access token from command line and it is the same as above but the expiration time.

Any idea about what can it be wrong?